# SubClassing in iPhone objective c to share the common class files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, shared-libraries, subclassing

I am very new to iPhone.
I have developed two version of an application in iphone. Here i have used individual class implementations depends upon version features.

For example ' `ListViewController`' class have `.h,.m, xib` files. with the **same name in two versions**, but different in some part (little bit difference) code implementation.

In 1st `'ListViewController'` version shows only a table view.
In 2nd version 'ListViewController' shows tableview and a button just bello the table view, to set the reminders (alarm).

So just the difference in **InterfaceBuilder** `*button* (AlarmButton)` & **in Code** *`button action -(IBAction)SetReminder.`*

Now I need to put all the same classes in a library (Common folder) for the two projects v1&v2,

Now i need to implemente 'ListViewController' as common for both versions ***using subClassing***.

How do I achieve that, any help or examples or link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share the same code between classes generally we use inheritance but there is a very cool feature added in objective-c that is category, find the tutorial link below: 
http://iphone-obsessed.blogspot.in/2010/05/tutorial-creating-class-categories-in.html

Might Help...!!

Answer (score 1):

To create a subclass you just need to create  header and implementation files they should look like this

```
// header file
@interface MySubclassName : ListViewController

@end


// implementation file
#import "MySubclassName.h"
@implementation MySubclassName

// methods you want to subclass

@end
```